# Trigger FOR EACH ROW

Tags: mysql, triggers

Hi guys I am trying to make a trigger so that if the price of a beer increased more than $1 then I add the name of the bar to the RIPOFFBAR table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER PriceTrig
 AFTER UPDATE ON Sells
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.price > OLD.price + 1.00)
THEN
INSERT INTO RipoffBars(bar)
 VALUES(NEW.bar);
 END IF;
 END;
```

and as you can see I used FOR EACH ROW BEGIN with IF statement
But for some reason it is not working any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

First mistake you have made that is using **" trigger_time = AFTER "** when you are trying to update the row. According mysql manual :

In a BEFORE trigger, you can also change its value with SET NEW.col_name = value if you have the UPDATE privilege for it. This means you can use a trigger to modify the values to be inserted into a new row or used to update a row. `(Such a SET statement has no effect in an AFTER trigger because the row change will have already occurred.)`

For details check the manual from here : 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html

I have created two tables, insert data and write the trigger following your information :

**CREATE TABLE :**

Table 1 : `create table sells (beer_name varchar(200),beer_price int(20));`

Table 2 : `create table ripo_off_bar (beer_name varchar(200));`

**INSERT :**

```
Insert into sells values("Root Beer", 2);
```

**TRIGGER :**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER price_update BEFORE UPDATE ON sells

FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 

IF(NEW.beer_price > OLD.beer_price + 1) THEN  

INSERT INTO ripo_off_bar (beer_name) VALUES (NEW.beer_name);

END IF;

END;$$
```

**UPDATE :**

```
update sells SET beer_price=8 where beer_name="Root Beer";
```

After that if you **VIEW** the ripo_off_bar table you will see there has been added your updated beer_name information !:

**VIEW :**

```
SELECT * FROM ripo_off_bar;
```

I have added screenshot of coded also. Hope these will help you to complete your task. Happy coding !!!

[image: Trigger Creation & Updated value]